# ruby: stripping backslashes from string

Tags: mysql, ruby, regex, string

I'm running into an issue trying to parse through a predefined nessus xml report and dump the data into a mysql database. Some of the data i'm dumping into the database has the following characters which is making mysql barf obviously: ' " \

I am able to remove the single and double quotes, but is there a method to escape an escape? Keep in mind i dont have control over what is stored once it is iterated. Here's an example:

```
myvariable = "this is some bloated nessus output that has a bunch of crappy data and this domain\username" 

myvariable.gsub!(/\\/, '')
```

The following gsub wont remove the backslash because it already thinks \u is escaped.

here is the actual code that is parsing the nessus xml file:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
#
# Database Schema:                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
# VALUES(Id (leave null), start time, hostname, host_ip, operating_system, scan_name, plugin_id, cve, cvss, risk, port, description, synopsis, solution, see_also, plugin_output, vuln_crit, vuln_high, vuln_med)                             
#                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
require 'mysql'                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
require 'nessus'                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

begin                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         



con = Mysql.new 'yourdbhost', 'yourdbuser', 'yourpass', 'nessusdb'                                                                                                                                                                                 
scanTime = Time.now.to_i                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

Nessus::Parse.new("bloated.xml", :version => 2) do |scan|                                                                                                                                       


    scan.each_host do |host| # enumerate each host                                                                                                                                                                                            
        start_time = host.start_time                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        next if host.event_count.zero? # skip host if there are no events to dump in the db                                                                                                                                                   

        host.each_event do |event|                                                                                                                                                                                                            
#            '#{event.see_also.join('\s').gsub(/\"|\'|\\/, '')}'                                                                                                                                                                              
#            '#{event.solution.gsub!(/\"|\'|\\/, '')}'                                                                                                                                                                                        
#            '#{event.synopsis.gsub!(/\"|\'|\\/, '')}'                                                                                                                                                                                        
            con.query( \                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                "INSERT INTO nessus_scans VALUES \                                                                                                                                                                                            
                (NULL, \                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                '#{scanTime}', \                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                '#{host.hostname}', \                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                '#{host.ip}', \                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                '#{host.operating_system}',\                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                '#{scan.title}', \                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                '#{event.plugin_id}', \                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                '#{event.cve}', \                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                '#{event.cvss_base_score}',\                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                '#{event.risk}', \                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                '#{event.port}', \                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                '#{event.description.gsub!(/\"|\'|\\/, '')}', \                                                                                                                                                                               
                NULL, \                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                NULL, \                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                NULL, \                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                NULL, \                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                NULL, \                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                NULL, \                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                NULL \)                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                ")                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

        end # end xml file iteration                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    end # end scan.each_host iteration                                                                                                                                                                                                        
end # end host.each_event iteration                                                                                                                                                                                                           

rescue Mysql::Error => e                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    puts e.errno                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    puts e.error                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
ensure                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    con.close if con                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
end
```

Comment: where is my variable coming from? it thinks it's escaped because of the double quotes around my variable

Comment: here is the line in the code that is trying to parse strings that have a backslash in them:

'#{event.description.gsub!(/\"|\'|\\/, '')}'

here is the actual code for reference: https://github.com/zachsis/nessus-db-report/blob/master/xmltodatabase.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a gigantic [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/) because you're not doing any escaping here. Using the MySQL driver directly is an extremely bad idea. At the very least use a database layer like [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) or [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). The singular reason why MySQL is "barfing" is because you're not using it correctly, you **must** escape.

The easiest fix for this mess is to use the [`escape_string`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/tmtm/ruby-mysql/Mysql.escape_string) method, but you need to do this for every single value, something that quickly becomes tedious. A proper database layer allows you to use parameterized queries that handle escaping for you, which is why I strongly encourage that.

Comment: escape_string is what i was looking for. Thanks for the help. This is my 3rd day coding ruby and first time writing to a database from a program so your input is appreciated. thanks

Comment: No trouble at all. Just be very careful when writing SQL code by hand. I've found Sequel is a good compromise between being low-level enough it doesn't get in the way, and providing a lot of support when writing queries. ActiveRecord is a much bigger commitment but gives you a lot more abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

for example, you can use brackets:

```
myvariable.gsub!(/[\\]+/, '')
```